# Using jQuery/JS, how do I convert this string into 2 arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How do I convert this string:

```
{ array1: [ 'mary', 'steve', 'george' ],
  array2: [ 'dog', 'cat', 'hobbit' ] }
```

Into 2 arrays?

I tried the following but I got a syntax error.

```
var array = JSON.parse("[" +string + "]");
```

Thank you.

EDIT

I tried :

```
var results = $('#progress').text();
var obj = JSON.parse(results);
var array1 = obj.array1;
var array2 = obj.array2;
console.log(array1);
```

But I'm getting `unexpected token a`

EDIT 2

I'm using this to retrieve the info from mongodb:

```
BlogPost.find(query, {"array1":"true", "array2":"true", "_id":0}, function(err, results){

  query.exec(function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!post) return next(); // 404

    res.render('post/view.jade', { post: post, comments: promise, results: results });
  })
})
```

Comment: Are you sure it is a string?  The way you have it posted, it is already a JSON object.  You could get the two arrays by using `obj.array1` and `obj.array2`.

Comment: You want to convert them into 2 arrays or you want to merge all the arrays into 1?

Comment: I want to have 2 arrays, that I can manipulate client-side

Comment: @Squirrl your json isn't formatted right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't a string, it's an object. To convert to a valid JSON object you only need to make your keys strings. i.e.

```
{ 
    'array1': [ 'mary', 'steve', 'george' ],
    'array2': [ 'dog', 'cat', 'hobbit' ] 
}
```

**UPDATE: It looks like you simply want to access the arrays**

To do so simply assign to a variable and access like this

```
var arrays = { 
    array1: [ 'mary', 'steve', 'george' ],
    array2: [ 'dog', 'cat', 'hobbit' ] 
}

console.log(arrays.array1);
console.log(arrays.array2);
```

Comment: How do I do that? I'm getting if from mongo without strings? (i.e. no single quotes on the keys)

Comment: Are you just trying to use it as a normal object? If so you can just do the above. Updating now

Comment: I'm trying to have 2 arrays that I can loop through browser side.  I got the above text I posted from my mongo find() request.  I tried JSON.stringy on the server side, and that put quotes around everything, but I still wasn't able to separate them into 2 arrays.  Thanks :)

Comment: No, it's coming back undefined.  That is probably because I'm retrieving it using `var results = $('#progress').text();` and that's turning it into a string.  And thus `console.log(results.array1);` is undefined.  How does one typically access a JSON object from a public JS file?  I think my posting into a HTML ID is the wrong approach all together.

Comment: Your problem is that you are just rendering out the promise returned from Mongo, you should really be either using a js templating system, or build your HTML from the promise returned, then inject it into your site.

Comment: Im using this jade `#progress= results`, but yes I see you point. Thanks for the advice.  One last follow up, Is there a way to inject arrays, or does that have to be built client-side?

Comment: Inject them in what way? Simply print them into the DOM?

Comment: Inject them, so that I may say `console.log(array1[2])` or run a loop, or have the features of an array without constructing one on the client side?

Comment: Or do I have to inject it as a string, and than run var array = injectedString.split(','); or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

I would just do

```
var obj = JSON.parse(string);
var array1 = obj.array1;
var array2 = obj.array2;
```

Comment: Could you tell me why my json isn't formatted correctly with what I've posted in the edit above?

Comment: @Squirrl it would help to know exactly what `results` is.

Comment: `results` is `{ array1: [ 'mary', 'steve', 'george' ],
  array2: [ 'dog', 'cat', 'hobbit' ] }`, at least that's what is looks like after it renders using this jade `#progress= results`